# Printing a character from a file after incrementing the file pointer

Tags: c

In file.txt I have the following content:

```
We are 
in 2012
```

I want to print the second char i.e "e", but the following program is showing blank.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()

{
char c;
FILE *file;
file = fopen("file.txt", "r");


 c = getc(file+1); 
     putchar(c);

    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

How do I print the second char correctly? (When I just pass file in getc, then it prints w.)

Comment: I don't think incrementing the file pointer will yield the wanted result. I don't think that's the file CONTENT pointer.

Comment: Think about validating an answer if one of them answer your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

file is not a pointer to a memory buffer.

```
  FILE* file;
```

It's pointer to a file structure. By providing (file+1) argument to getc(), you just provided it with an uninitialized area as input.

The answer is pretty simple : either call getc() twice;
or, as it may be an exercise, you can use fseek(), to move the file pointer to the right location. It becomes :

```
  fseek(file, 1, SEEK_SET);
  c = getc(file);
  putchar(c);
```

Answer (score 2):

The `FILE *` object that `fopen` returns is not the stream pointer, it is an abstract data structure that the file handling functions use. To advance the stream pointer use [fseek](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fseek).

`file + 1` instead points to the first memory address after the `FILE` object and using it for anything other than comparing pointers is undefined behaviour. So `c = getc(file + 1);` is undefined behaviour and could very well crash your program, or do nothing at all.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use math operations on a FILE pointer.

```
 c = getc(file); 
 c = getc(file); 
 putchar(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `getc` several times:

```
 c = getc(file); // Get first character
 c = getc(file); // Get second character

 putchar(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
c = getc(file+1);
```

it tries to increment pointer `file` by 1, making it point to the `FILE*` that follows in memory (i.e. to the address `sizeof(FILE)` further) and then it passes this invalid pointer to `getc` resulting in *undefined behavior*.

You could use [`fgets`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) to extract whole line and access some specific character directly:

```
char line[100];
if (fgets(line, 100, file)) {
    c = line[1];
}
```